# Heroku Application Routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, blogs

I have a simple rails website on heroku, using active_admin to manage associates and blog(using Blogit Blog engine). I keep getting the following error (heroku logsheroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/blog/posts/). I'm unable to see the index page with all the blog posts. This only happens after I add a new post, if there are no posts, I get no errors, index is displayed with Sorry No Posts. The minuted I add a post, i get the error.

The app works find on my local machine Using Rails 3.2.12 with Ruby 1.9.3 and sqllite.

I would appreciate any thoughts or help troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: It's hard to guess what the answer is without seeing the error message. I'm guessing you have a condition in your view or controller that says if @posts.any? do x, else do y. I'm also guessing that there is a bug in x, which only executes when you have some posts. To get any clearer about it, you'll need to provide the error message or at least the view / controller code.

Comment: Thank you Nick,you pointed me in the right direction, the posts were being parsed by Pygments which wasn't installed.